# In flutter, CustomPaint() seems to behave strangely when used within scaffold/container widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

So, I am trying to draw a diagonal line on the screen using CustomPaint widget in flutter. from within the CustomPaint widget, I am calling my CustomPainter class called BottomCurvePainter. The code for which is something like this.

```
class BottomCurvePainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    // TODO: implement paint
    Paint paint = Paint();
    paint.color = Colors.black;
    paint.style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
    paint.strokeWidth = 5.0;

    Path path = Path();
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    // TODO: implement shouldRepaint
    //throw UnimplementedError();
    return true;
  }
}
```

The way I am calling this in my home is as below:-

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
          body: Container(
          color: Colors.orange,
          child: CustomPaint(
            painter: BottomCurvePainter(),
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

but this does not seem to work. However I can make it work if I remove the Scaffold widget and directly return the Container, something like this -

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
          color: Colors.orange,
          child: CustomPaint(
            painter: BottomCurvePainter(),
          ),
    );
  }
}
```

Can someone explain why wrapping the container in a scaffold is not working? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify the width and height properties of the container.
It's not appearing because you didn't specify the dimensions (or the constraints) of the container that'll take place in the scaffold.
Take a look on [container widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html) from the flutter docs.

Comment: Isn't container widget suppose to take the size of its child if no constraints defined? Also I am not specifying any height or width in the other scenario i.e. when using the container directly. However that seems to work fine.

Comment: That's true a container takes if the constraints of child, But what's the constraints of the child. The custom paint takes two props,  child and painter. The child which will define the constraints of your painter.But above you didnt define it, so it didnt take any constraints. The other scenario, when you use container directly, You set the container as a home to the material app with no scaffold, so it will automatically take the media query of the page and set the height & width of the page to the container's constraints.